# Advice on detecting if Phone Camera is facing a GPS coordinate

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gps, augmented-reality

I'd like to ask for any advice on available implementations / algorithms examples, and many thanks in advance!

Currently I am developing an Android Augmented Reality (AR) Navigation App in Unity with C#, I have already implemented pathfinding and retrieving phone camera and location services.
With all the available data, I need to develop a way to calibrate the app before it is able to offer navigation directions.

My question is how I would go about detecting that the phone's camera (Assuming back-facing), is directed towards a target GPS location?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Current location + compass should do it, I imagine.

Comment: @john Sorry for the late reply, I've been busy developing towards what you suggested. The solution was a combination of building an Android Plugin that accesses the Accelerometer, Compass and GPS to calculate if the phone camera was facing a GPS coordinate. Cheers!

Comment: You might want to share your solution as an answer to your own question. If you do, tag me and I'll upvote it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To what @[John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john) suggested, I've built an Android Plugin that uses the SensorManager library, to calculate using Magnetic Field and Accelerometer sensor values, combined with the orientation of the phone camera, to work out the Azimuth of the back-facing camera.